# Accents misaligned with unicode-math and STIX2

Tags: luatex, accents, unicode-math, stix

While using STIX2 with LuaLaTeX and unicode-math, I found out that accents such as `\hat` or `\bar` aren't aligned properly with the letters:

[image]

I haven't noticed any similar problems with XITS with the same configuration…

Is there any workaround for this? I'd reckon that given the relative popularity of this font, some solution should already exist somewhere.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}

\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
    \bar v
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: Added log

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/Arch Linux)  (format=lualatex 2019.6.24)  25 JUN 2019 09:28
 restricted system commands enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2019-02-14 2.96 luaotfload entry point
Lua module: luaotfload-init 2019-02-14 2.96 luaotfload submodule / initializatio
n
Lua module: lualibs 2019-02-14 2.64 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2019-02-14 2.64 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
Lua module: luaotfload-log 2019-02-14 2.96 luaotfload submodule / logging
Lua module: luaotfload-parsers 2019-02-14 2.96 luaotfload submodule / filelist
Lua module: luaotfload-configuration 2019-02-14 2.96 luaotfload submodule / conf
ig file reader
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is /home/free/.texlive/texmf-var/luatex
-cache/generic/names.
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader “fontloader-2019-02-14.lua” from kpse
-resolved path “/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-2019-02
-14.lua”.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@state = 1
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 2
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 3
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version “3.107”
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Lua module: luaotfload-loaders 2019-02-14 2.96 luaotfload submodule / callback h
andling
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua module: luaotfload-database 2019-02-14 2.96 luaotfload submodule / database
Lua module: luaotfload-colors 2019-02-14 2.96 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 4
Lua module: luaotfload-resolvers 2019-02-14 2.96 luaotfload submodule / resolver
s
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is /home/free/.texlive/texmf-var/luatex
-cache/generic/names.
Lua module: luaotfload-features 2019-02-14 2.96 luaotfload submodule / features
Lua module: luaotfload-letterspace 2019-02-14 2.96 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-auxiliary 2019-02-14 2.96 luaotfload submodule / auxiliar
y functions
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
.
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.053 seconds
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /home/free/.texlive/texmf-var/
luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2019-04-06 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2019-04-06 L3 programming layer (code)
\ucharcat@table=\catcodetable5
\c_max_int=\count88
\l_tmpa_int=\count89
\l_tmpb_int=\count90
\g_tmpa_int=\count91
\g_tmpb_int=\count92
\g__kernel_prg_map_int=\count93
\c__ior_term_ior=\count94
\c_log_iow=\count95
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count96
\l__iow_line_target_int=\count97
\l__iow_one_indent_int=\count98
\l__iow_indent_int=\count99
\c_zero_dim=\dimen103
\c_max_dim=\dimen104
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen105
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen106
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen107
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen108
\c_zero_skip=\skip43
\c_max_skip=\skip44
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip45
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip46
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip47
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip48
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
\l_keys_choice_int=\count100
\l__intarray_loop_int=\count101
\c__intarray_sp_dim=\dimen109
\g__intarray_font_int=\count102
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count103
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count104
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count105
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count106
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count107
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count108
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count109
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count110
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count111
\g__fp_array_int=\count112
\l__fp_array_loop_int=\count113
\l__sort_length_int=\count114
\l__sort_min_int=\count115
\l__sort_top_int=\count116
\l__sort_max_int=\count117
\l__sort_true_max_int=\count118
\l__sort_block_int=\count119
\l__sort_begin_int=\count120
\l__sort_end_int=\count121
\l__sort_A_int=\count122
\l__sort_B_int=\count123
\l__sort_C_int=\count124
\l__tl_analysis_normal_int=\count125
\l__tl_analysis_index_int=\count126
\l__tl_analysis_nesting_int=\count127
\l__tl_analysis_type_int=\count128
\l__regex_internal_a_int=\count129
\l__regex_internal_b_int=\count130
\l__regex_internal_c_int=\count131
\l__regex_balance_int=\count132
\l__regex_group_level_int=\count133
\l__regex_mode_int=\count134
\c__regex_cs_in_class_mode_int=\count135
\c__regex_cs_mode_int=\count136
\l__regex_catcodes_int=\count137
\l__regex_default_catcodes_int=\count138
\c__regex_catcode_L_int=\count139
\c__regex_catcode_O_int=\count140
\c__regex_catcode_A_int=\count141
\c__regex_all_catcodes_int=\count142
\l__regex_show_lines_int=\count143
\l__regex_min_state_int=\count144
\l__regex_max_state_int=\count145
\l__regex_left_state_int=\count146
\l__regex_right_state_int=\count147
\l__regex_capturing_group_int=\count148
\l__regex_min_pos_int=\count149
\l__regex_max_pos_int=\count150
\l__regex_curr_pos_int=\count151
\l__regex_start_pos_int=\count152
\l__regex_success_pos_int=\count153
\l__regex_curr_char_int=\count154
\l__regex_curr_catcode_int=\count155
\l__regex_last_char_int=\count156
\l__regex_case_changed_char_int=\count157
\l__regex_curr_state_int=\count158
\l__regex_step_int=\count159
\l__regex_min_active_int=\count160
\l__regex_max_active_int=\count161
\l__regex_replacement_csnames_int=\count162
\l__regex_match_count_int=\count163
\l__regex_min_submatch_int=\count164
\l__regex_submatch_int=\count165
\l__regex_zeroth_submatch_int=\count166
\g__regex_trace_regex_int=\count167
\c_empty_box=\box27
\l_tmpa_box=\box28
\l_tmpb_box=\box29
\g_tmpa_box=\box30
\g_tmpb_box=\box31
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen110
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen111
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen112
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen113
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen114
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen115
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen116
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen117
\l__box_internal_box=\box32
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box33
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen118
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen119
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen120
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen121
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen122
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen123
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen124
\c_empty_coffin=\box34
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box35
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box36
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box37
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box38
\g_tmpa_coffin=\box39
\g_tmpb_coffin=\box40
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen125
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen126
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen127
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen129
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen130
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen131
\c__coffin_empty_coffin=\box41
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box42
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box43
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box44
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen132
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen133
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen134
\g__file_internal_ior=\read1
\l__seq_internal_a_int=\count168
\l__seq_internal_b_int=\count169
\c__deprecation_minus_one=\count170
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def
File: l3pdfmode.def 2019-04-06 v L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
\l__driver_color_stack_int=\count171
))
Package: unicode-math 2019/03/04 v0.8o Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-luatex.sty
Package: unicode-math-luatex 2019/03/04 v0.8o Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLa
TeX

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2019-03-05 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count172
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count173
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count174
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count175
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
Package: l3keys2e 2019-03-05 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
Package: fontspec 2019/03/15 v2.7c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
Lua module: fontspec 2019/03/15 2.7c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
Package: fontspec-luatex 2019/03/15 v2.7c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count176
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count177
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count178
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count179
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count180
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count181
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count182
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count183
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count184
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count185
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count186
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen135
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen136
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen137

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def
File: tuenc.def 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding TU on input line 82.
))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 3783.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 3788.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 3793.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 3798.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 3828.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \emph on input line 3853.
))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook.sty
Package: filehook 2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty
Package: fix-cm 2015/01/14 v1.1t fixes to LaTeX

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def
File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/lualatex-math/lualatex-math.sty
Package: lualatex-math 2019/01/21 v1.8 Patches for mathematics typesetting with 
LuaLaTeX

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2018/08/19 v2.5f e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count187
)
Lua module: lualatex-math 2013/08/03 1.3 Patches for mathematics typesetting wit
h LuaLaTeX)
\g__um_fam_int=\count188
\g__um_fonts_used_int=\count189
\l__um_primecount_int=\count190
\g__um_primekern_muskip=\muskip16

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-table.tex)))

Package fontspec Info: Font family 'STIX2Math.otf(0)' created for font
(fontspec)             'STIX2Math.otf' with options
(fontspec)             [Renderer=Basic,BoldItalicFont={},ItalicFont={},SmallCaps
Font={},Script=Math,FontAdjustment={\__um_luatex_copy_fontdimens:
(fontspec)             }].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[STIX2Math.otf]:mode=base;script=math;language=DFLT;"

(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \__um_luatex_copy_fontdimens: 


Package fontspec Info: Font family 'STIX2Math.otf(1)' created for font
(fontspec)             'STIX2Math.otf' with options
(fontspec)             [Renderer=Basic,BoldItalicFont={},ItalicFont={},SmallCaps
Font={},Script=Math,SizeFeatures={{Size=8.5-},{Size=6.25-8.5,Font=STIX2Math.otf,
Style=MathScript},{Size=-6.25,Font=STIX2Math.otf,Style=MathScriptScript}},FontAd
justment={\__um_luatex_copy_fontdimens:
(fontspec)             }].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <8.5->"[STIX2Math.otf]:mode=base;script=math;language=DFL
T;"<6.25-8.5>"[STIX2Math.otf]:mode=base;script=math;language=DFLT;+ssty=0;"<-6.2
5>"[STIX2Math.otf]:mode=base;script=math;language=DFLT;+ssty=1;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \__um_luatex_copy_fontdimens: 

LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/STIX2Math.otf(1)/m/n on input line 5.

LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/STIX2Math.otf(1)/bx/n on input line 
5.

Package fontspec Info: STIX2Math scale = 1.0001.


Package fontspec Info: STIX2Math scale = 1.0001.


Package fontspec Info: STIX2Math scale = 1.0001.


Package fontspec Info: STIX2Math scale = 1.0001.


Package fontspec Info: Font family 'STIX2Math.otf(2)' created for font
(fontspec)             'STIX2Math.otf' with options
(fontspec)             [Renderer=Basic,BoldItalicFont={},ItalicFont={},SmallCaps
Font={},Script=Math,SizeFeatures={{Size=8.5-},{Size=6.25-8.5,Font=STIX2Math.otf,
Style=MathScript},{Size=-6.25,Font=STIX2Math.otf,Style=MathScriptScript}},FontAd
justment={\__um_luatex_copy_fontdimens:
(fontspec)             },ScaleAgain=1.0001,FontAdjustment={\fontdimen 8\font
(fontspec)             =6.4pt\relax \fontdimen 9\font =5.84999pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 10\font =4.7pt\relax \fontdimen 11\font
(fontspec)             =6.4pt\relax \fontdimen 12\font =5.84999pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 13\font =3.59999pt\relax \fontdimen 14\font
(fontspec)             =3.59999pt\relax \fontdimen 15\font =2.51999pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 16\font =2.09999pt\relax \fontdimen 17\font
(fontspec)             =2.09999pt\relax \fontdimen 18\font =2.29999pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 19\font =1.59999pt\relax \fontdimen 22\font
(fontspec)             =2.57999pt\relax \fontdimen 20\font =0pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 21\font =0pt\relax }].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <8.5->s*[1.0001]"[STIX2Math.otf]:mode=base;script=math;la
nguage=DFLT;"<6.25-8.5>s*[1.0001]"[STIX2Math.otf]:mode=base;script=math;language
=DFLT;+ssty=0;"<-6.25>s*[1.0001]"[STIX2Math.otf]:mode=base;script=math;language=
DFLT;+ssty=1;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \__um_luatex_copy_fontdimens: \fontdimen 8\font
(fontspec)             =6.4pt\relax \fontdimen 9\font =5.84999pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 10\font =4.7pt\relax \fontdimen 11\font
(fontspec)             =6.4pt\relax \fontdimen 12\font =5.84999pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 13\font =3.59999pt\relax \fontdimen 14\font
(fontspec)             =3.59999pt\relax \fontdimen 15\font =2.51999pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 16\font =2.09999pt\relax \fontdimen 17\font
(fontspec)             =2.09999pt\relax \fontdimen 18\font =2.29999pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 19\font =1.59999pt\relax \fontdimen 22\font
(fontspec)             =2.57999pt\relax \fontdimen 20\font =0pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 21\font =0pt\relax 

LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMS' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `symbols' in the math version `normal' on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> TU/STIX2Math.otf(2)/m/n on input line 5
.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMS' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `symbols' in the math version `bold' on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> TU/STIX2Math.otf(2)/bx/n on input line 
5.

Package fontspec Info: STIX2Math scale = 0.9999.


Package fontspec Info: STIX2Math scale = 0.9999.


Package fontspec Info: STIX2Math scale = 0.9999.


Package fontspec Info: STIX2Math scale = 0.9999.


Package fontspec Info: Font family 'STIX2Math.otf(3)' created for font
(fontspec)             'STIX2Math.otf' with options
(fontspec)             [Renderer=Basic,BoldItalicFont={},ItalicFont={},SmallCaps
Font={},Script=Math,SizeFeatures={{Size=8.5-},{Size=6.25-8.5,Font=STIX2Math.otf,
Style=MathScript},{Size=-6.25,Font=STIX2Math.otf,Style=MathScriptScript}},FontAd
justment={\__um_luatex_copy_fontdimens:
(fontspec)             },ScaleAgain=0.9999,FontAdjustment={\fontdimen 8\font
(fontspec)             =0.68pt\relax \fontdimen 9\font =1.34999pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 10\font =1.34999pt\relax \fontdimen 11\font
(fontspec)             =3.0pt\relax \fontdimen 12\font =6.7pt\relax \fontdimen
(fontspec)             13\font =0pt\relax }].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <8.5->s*[0.9999]"[STIX2Math.otf]:mode=base;script=math;la
nguage=DFLT;"<6.25-8.5>s*[0.9999]"[STIX2Math.otf]:mode=base;script=math;language
=DFLT;+ssty=0;"<-6.25>s*[0.9999]"[STIX2Math.otf]:mode=base;script=math;language=
DFLT;+ssty=1;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             and font adjustment code:
(fontspec)             \__um_luatex_copy_fontdimens: \fontdimen 8\font
(fontspec)             =0.68pt\relax \fontdimen 9\font =1.34999pt\relax
(fontspec)             \fontdimen 10\font =1.34999pt\relax \fontdimen 11\font
(fontspec)             =3.0pt\relax \fontdimen 12\font =6.7pt\relax \fontdimen
(fontspec)             13\font =0pt\relax 

LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMX' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `largesymbols' in the math version `normal' on input line 5.

LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> TU/STIX2Math.otf(3)/m/n on input line 5
.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OMX' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `largesymbols' in the math version `bold' on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> TU/STIX2Math.otf(3)/bx/n on input line 
5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/STIX2Math.otf(2)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.00107pt on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/STIX2Math.otf(2)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 7.00075pt on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/STIX2Math.otf(2)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 5.50058pt on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/STIX2Math.otf(3)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 9.99893pt on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/STIX2Math.otf(3)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 6.99925pt on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/STIX2Math.otf(3)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 5.4994pt on input line 5.

Package lualatex-math Info: I'm going to patch macro \frac.


No file test.aux.

\openout1 = test.aux
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/STIX2Math.otf(1)/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/lmr/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/bx/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/bx/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/bx/n on input line 6.
[1

{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux))

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 16428 strings out of 494300
 125171,794899 words of node,token memory allocated
 419 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 6 attribute, 49 glue_spec,
 6 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 1:2,2:21,3:4,4:1,5:22,6:2,7:20,8:2,9:12
 20465 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 41 fonts using 15258015 bytes
 49i,4n,109p,967b,446s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,100000s
</usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf></usr/shar
e/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/stix2-otf/STIX2Math.otf>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 4609 bytes).

PDF statistics: 22 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 12 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)
```

Comment: Just for testing, have you tried setting the font first and the load unicode math. It probably does not make any difference

Comment: It looks okay for me, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/McvHc.png. Can you share your log-file?

Comment: Looks OK for me, with both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX.

Comment: I added the log

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using an old version of the STIX2 font. Use the one that comes with TeX Live 2019.

I was able to reproduce with `Version 2.00 b137`

[image]

but not with `Version 2.01 b141` from TeX Live 2019

[image]

Comment: Weird, I did upgrade to TeX Live 2019 yesterday, but it didn't resolve the problem. After checking the OTF, it appears the version of the font is still 2.00… It could be an Archlinux packaging problem.

Comment: Are you sure that it is bundled in TeX Live 2019 ? I just checked and in fact in the texlive-fontsextra package in archlinux contains the 2.00 version, whereas the latest version updated in april is 2.01. It might be a packaging problem.

Comment: Looks like the new version from CTAN appeared on the 22nd of April, but its inclusion in TeX Live was on the 2nd of May in revision 50948, whereas the archlinux package is at revision 50876. I'll consider using tllocalmgr or installing via the official method instead, thank you!

Comment: Alright, I've reinstalled everything using the official method, got the new version of STIX2 but it still wasn't working. I checked that luaotfload wasn't picking up any leftover fonts, but to no avail. After checking the log file, lualatex was picking up the STIX2Math.otf that was in the same directory that I had extracted from the arch package. Removing that file then resolved everything. Thank you very much!