# \hat{} and \tilde{} commands result in misaligned accents with bold math symbols

Tags: math-mode, luatex, texlive

I would like to use accents on bold characters in math equations with the Utopia font. It appears that the accent is not properly shifted to the left when using `\hat{\mathbf{x}}` for example. Using `\mathbf{\hat{x}}` does not give good results either.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fourier-otf}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    X \quad \hat{X} &\qquad x \quad \hat{x} \\
    \mathbf{X} \quad \hat{\mathbf{X}} &\qquad \mathbf{x} \quad \hat{\mathbf{x}} \\
    \mathbf{X} \quad \mathbf{\hat{X}} &\qquad \mathbf{x} \quad \mathbf{\hat{x}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

and the result that I get:

[image]

A similar issue was [reported here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497226/accents-misaligned-with-unicode-math-and-stix2) with the STIX2 font. The problem was related to the version of the font used but I don't know if this could be the issue here. According to tlmgr, the version of the `fourier` package is 54090 (2.2).

I can get properly aligned accents if I load `fourier` instead of `fourier-otf`, but this results in many other issues in my text related to font encoding.

Is there a simple way to make the accents work with bold maths?

Comment: I don't think that the earlier posting to which you provided a link has much bearing on the issue caused by combining `\mathbf` with accenting commands such as `\hat` and `\tilde`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You asked,

> Is there a simple way to make the accents work with bold maths?

Short answer: Yes. :-)

Slightly longer answer: Since you use Lua(La)TeX and the `unicide-math` package, simply replace all instances of `\mathbf` with `\symbf`.

[image]

Please see sections 3.1, "New Commands", and 4.4, "Legacy 'maths' alphabet commands", of the user guide of the [unicode-math](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) package for more information on the differences between `\mathbf` and `\symbf` (as well as `\mathit` vs. `\symit`, `\mathup` vs. `\symup`, `\mathrm` vs. `\symrm`, and `\mathsf` and `\symsf`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier-otf}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
X \quad \hat{X} &\qquad x \quad \hat{x} \\
\symbf{X} \quad \hat{\symbf{X}} &\qquad \symbf{x} \quad \hat{\symbf{x}} \\
\symbf{X} \quad \symbf{\hat{X}} &\qquad \symbf{x} \quad \symbf{\hat{x}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\symbf` does not work in jupyter notebooks; though after exporting with pdflatex the hat is shown properly.

Comment: @Friedrich--СлаваУкраїні - Thanks. I must confess that I'm not familiar with Project Jupyter. Does it uses TeX/LaTeX or, rather, Mathjaxx, as the underlying rendering engine?

Comment: Jupyter seems to use `MathJax`.

Comment: @Friedrich--СлаваУкраїні - That would explain why code that requires LuaLaTeX doesn't run properly.